# Can someone help me to integrate Scipy in Kivy?

Tags: android, scipy, kivy, buildozer

Does anyone know why I'm encountering this error when trying to use the scipy library in Kivy? I've followed the steps outlined in [NDK version conflict in buildozer for Kivy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73539112/ndk-version-conflict-in-buildozer-for-kivy-app), and I'm getting an error that says:

[DEBUG](/home/isabel/Escritorio/DIPC/kivy/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/f951):        arm-linux-androideabi-gfortran: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

But those files exist.
Can someone help me?